# Is this complex numbers inequality true?

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers

If m,n,p are distinct complex numbers of moduli 1, then |m+n|+|n+p|+|p+m| does not exceed 3.

My trial was to put m=cosA+isinA and so on, and I needed to prove that sum of |cos((A-B)/2)|<=3/2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This inequality is clearly not true. Just take any three complex numbers which are suitably close together on the unit circle. For example
$$(m,n,p)=(1,e^{0.1i},e^{-0.1i})$$
then we have
$$|m+n|+|n+p|+|p+m|=5.9850094\dots\gt3$$
In fact the value of this expression can be made arbitrarily close to $6$ by choosing suitably close $m,n,p$.